# What traits to highlight for a management role?

Tags: management

I am applying for a variety of business management roles within companies and have not been very successful so far, not even getting to the phone interview stage.

My experience in my previous company includes being a junior manager of one "core" team and project manager for several teams arching across the company. I have done very well at all, and that's what my bosses say, with about two years of experience in this role.

I have applied for a number (approx 50) of similar roles at similar organizations, yet I must be doing something wrong as I have heard nothing positive so far, so I wanted to ask what could be the potential reasons for turning me down.

Am I too ambitious in trying to step from junior manager after just two years?
Could something be wrong with my skills?

P.S.: I have about 2 years pre-management experience in my specific function and 4-5 years education in my area. 
When I asked what could be wrong with my skills I meant my managerial skills. Everything else equal, it's the management skills that will matter most right (instead of the hard/technical/hands-on skills)? 
What I did before *specifically* should not be material to the question, right? (I also thought that if I keep it generic my question might be more helpful to others in my situation)

Comment: What have you done before managing?  Do you have a lack of previous experience?  That could be what's causing the lack of interest.

Comment: You don't tell us what your skills are, then you ask us if there's something wrong with your skills. Sweet. Did you use thew same approach when you wrote your resume and cover letters? Because that would go a long way to account for the non-response.

Comment: Do you have common language about your managerial skills/experience that you put into each resume? It might be good to add that to your question so that others can look at it.

Comment: One other suggestion I might offer...get your resume professionally written.  Expensive but totally worth it.  When you move into management, things get less cut and dry.  Your particular skill set becomes less important than an undefined [something] that potential employers are looking for.  Get help to most effectively highlight your non-technical skillset.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some things to stress:

1. **Initiative.**  Show that you're willing to take on work as needed, including work that no one asked you to do, but that you have independently identified as useful and that proved valuable to your organization.  Managers are expected to identify and prioritize work as instructed by their superiors, but it's at least as important to show that you can act independently and appropriately.
2. **Judgment.**  Did you make any decisions that saved your organization money?  Did you suggest changes that improved profitability, lowered costs, improved morale and effectiveness?   These are important traits for managerial roles.  If you can show dollar amounts, specific time savings, or the like, so much the better.
3. **Leadership.**  Each of the items in your resume should somehow highlight your ability to lead.  Stress any times that you guided a team, acted as a mentor, led a project, chaired a committee, etc.   Your resume should be full of "action" verbs like "led, instituted, guided, suggested, created".
4. **Integrity.**  This is more for the interview than the resume, but think of times when you had to make a difficult decision.  When did you do the right thing even though it was hard?  This is leadership in action.  (As an aside, if you find that the company has no interest in this quality, RUN AWAY!)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may be expecting too much.  It is never easy to move into a managerial role, and doing so without specific senior management experience on your resume...probably not going to happen.

You would better serve your goals by finding a company which will allow you to move into a managerial role after spending some time in the trenches.

When you interview with companies, find out how many of their managers were hired from the outside, and how many were hired from within.  Find a company that has a hire-from-within policy (and actually puts it into practice) and this is the company you want to work for.

And, as I mentioned in an earlier comment, get your resume redone by professionals.  Most recruiters will tell you that the reason you don't get to the interview stage can have more to do with how your resume presents you than with what it represents.  It isn't the "end users" who are probably screening you out, it's the HR people.  So it makes sense to tailor your "face" to match what they want to see.

I was in a similar situation many years ago.  I sent out resume after resume and never got a single interview.  Finally, in desperation I went to a professional resume writing service (I think it was the one from monster.com) and they had me write down pages and pages of description of all the things I had done at previous jobs.  Then they sent me a beautifully presented set of resumes (tailored to fit different types of positions, ie, design vs coding) complete with neat bullet points and precise, impressive sounding descriptions of relevant accomplishments.

I was really amazed at what a difference it made.  In just a couple of weeks I scored a handful of interviews and it wasn't long before I got an offer.